# Scrapy get text out of span

Tags: python, html, css, scrapy

URL: https://myanimelist.net/anime/236/Es_Otherwise

I trying to scrape the following content in URL:

[image]

I tried :

```
for i in response.css('span[class = dark_text]') :
    i.xpath('/following-sibling::text()')
```

or that current XPath who's don't work or I missed something...

```
aired_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[11]/text()')

producer_xpath = response.xpath("//*[@id='content']/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[12]/span/a/@href/text()")
licensor_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[13]/a/text()')
studio_xpath response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[14]/a/@href/title/text()')
studio_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[17]/text()')
str_rating_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[18]/text()')
ranked_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[20]/span/text()')
japanese_title_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[7]/text()')
source_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[15]/text()')
genre_xpath = [response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[16]/a[{0}]'.format(i)) for i in range(1,4)]
genre_xpath_v2 = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[16]/a/@href/text()')
number_of_users_rated_anime_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[19]/span[3]/text()')
popularity_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[21]/span/text()')
members_xpath = response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[22]/span/text()')
favorite_xpath =  response.xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/div/div[23]/span/text()')
```

but I figured out that some text are out of a span class, so I would like to get that text out of span with a css/XPath formula.

Comment: Hi. Please can you write a paragraph or so to better explain your question?

Comment: What language do you want to use? Do you have a deal with that site to scrape the content?

Comment: I use python with scrapy framework

Answer (score 1):

it simpler to just loop through div inside the table

```
foundH2 = False
response =  Selector(text=htmlString).xpath('//*[@id="content"]/table/tr/td[1]/div/*')

for resp in response:
  tagName = resp.xpath('name()').extract_first()
  if 'h2' == tagName:
    foundH2 = True
  if foundH2:
    # start adding 'info' after <h2>Alternative Titles</h2> found
    info = None
    if 'div' == tagName:
      for item in resp.xpath('.//text()').extract():
        if 'googletag.' in item: break
        item = item.strip()
        if item and item != ',':
          info = info + " " + item if info else item
      if info:
        print info
```

just my opinion, beautifulSoup is faster and better than scrapy.

Comment: Thanks it works, but what's name and googletag ? can you explain a bit your code please.

Comment: it `div` content after `Favorites: 27`, and it will stop loop after it found

Answer (score 0):

If you are only trying to scrap the information that you mentioned in the image you can just make use of

```
response.xpath('//div[@class="space-it"]//text()').extract()
```

Or i am unable to understand your question properly.

Comment: That following syntax return empty list

Comment: Have You changed the class name? actually the class name is spaceit

Comment: For a better Result You can try response.xpath('//div[@class="js-scrollfix-bottom"]//div[@class="spaceit"]

Comment: just it won't return you alternative name and type